# parse xml children with multiple children with same name, python

Tags: python, xml

I have xml:

```
<tree-root>
<sub1>it is sub1</sub1>
    <sub2>
    <sub3>sub3</sub3>
    <position>5584</position>
    <source-IP>
    <address-IP>2.104.54.11</address-IP>
    <address-IP>172.16.33.11</address-IP>
   </source-IP>
</sub2>
```

I would like to parse all the children inside of source-IP. The output shall be both IPs not just one.
I would like to have :

```
2.104.54.11
172.16.33.11
```

It is similar to [Parse XML with Python when multiple children share a name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255422/parse-xml-with-python-when-multiple-children-share-a-name), but I would kindly ask for all the code.

Thank you in advance.

I have tried `print(tree.find('sub2').find('source-IP').findall('address-IP').text);`, but only bringing the error:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Here is the full code:

```
print(tree.find('sub2').find('source-IP').find('address-IP').text)

{    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET  
tree = ET.parse('IPs.xml')  
root = tree.getroot()


print(root.text)
print(tree.find('sub1').text)                         
print(tree.find('sub2').find('sub3').text)  
print(tree.find('sub2').find('position').text)
 print('I would like to print all the IPs below, not just the first one')
print(tree.find('sub2').find('source-IP').find('address-IP').text)
print(tree.find('sub2').find('source-IP').find('address-IP').text)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.findall()` returns a list of items.  You need to loop over each of those items to get the text:

```
for address_ip in tree.find('sub2').find('source-IP').findall('address-IP'):
    print address_ip.text
```